# Button supposed to click 5 times through an string array, stop 5 secs and then continue(clicking 5 times) CONSISTENTLY, ERROR

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-button

My problem is I cant get my button to consistently click 5 times through a string array which is displayed in a TextView ,
 whenever the maxclicks(5) and currentnumber get to 5  it stops working  , Ive been trying to create if conditions to work around it, well somehow I have to manipulate my currentnumber to NOT be 5 because IF maxclicks == currentnumber my button is enabled.

In the Code below it stops just afte the first time of clicking 5 times.

so here  is the Code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


int currentnumber = 0;
int mod = 5;
TextView display = findViewById(R.id.tx);
Handler handler = new Handler();
int delay = 5000; 
int maxclicks = list.length;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    Resources res = getResources();
    final String[] list = res.getStringArray(R.array.xyz);
    final Button next_button = findViewById(R.id.next_btn);

    {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tx)).setText(list[currentnumber]);

next_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(currentnumber == maxclicks){
                    currentnumber = 0;
                }
                if (currentnumber % mod == 0) {
                    next_button.setEnabled(false);
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //the button will unlock after the delay specified
                            next_button.setEnabled(true);
                            currentnumber++;

                        }
                    }, delay);
                }
                else {
                    display.setText(list[currentnumber]);
                    currentnumber++;
                }
            }
        });


    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. we need to know what does "ERROR" mean for you, in this specific case.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are trying to do. setting maxclicks to 4 doesn't do much since the next line will then set it to 5.

Comment: So with Error I  mean that my Button wont click 5  times if I start clicking at the 6th string (after the timeout I put to the button) and I well I dont really know why but I assume its because the number in the array and maxclicks is the same


Sorry im bad at explaining what I basically want is my button to always click 5 times through an string array each time after its timed out and up again(which I did already).

Comment: In your code snippet, currentNumber will always stay zero. On the other hand maxclicks will never be zero: you can't change it from 5 to 4 since 5 != 0, so in fact maxclicks will always be 5. Maybe there is a typo or two in the code you posted?

Comment: I think you're looking for something like "currentNumber++" in your onClick() method. I'm making a lot of assumptions, but I'm guessing you're trying to allow for 5 clicks, but then disable the button after that?

Comment: Im looking to activate my button again to click 5 times because it is set off if (currentnumber == maxclicks)
yea I edited my code I do have currentnumber++ 
maybe I need another way to set my button off and on ?

Comment: I am surprised that the code even ran. TextView display should be initialized after you setContentView in onCreate. And I see list.length when list is never defined before that. list is a local variable in onCreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to SO :) I did my best to understand on your explanation,so this is my solution for your problem and don't forget you can make your vars global to avoid final and one element array thing:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private int currentnumber,mod,delay,Curclicks;
    private TextView display;
    private Handler handler;
    private Button next_button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);

        //Binding
        display = findViewById(R.id.tx);
        next_button = findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        //getResources
        Resources res = getResources();

        //getting the data ready
        String[] list = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7"};
        //assign vars
        handler = new Handler();
        currentnumber = 0;
        Curclicks=0;
        mod = 5;
        delay = 5000;
        //initial view
        next_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            if(currentnumber == list.length){
                currentnumber = 0;
            }
            if (Curclicks == mod-1) {
                next_button.setEnabled(false);
                display.setText(list[currentnumber]);
                currentnumber++;


                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //the button will unlock after the delay specified
                        next_button.setEnabled(true);
                        Curclicks = 0;
                    }
                }, delay);
            }
            else {
                display.setText(list[currentnumber]);
                currentnumber++;

            }
            Curclicks++;

        }

    });
}
    }
```